# Identifying and describing the language accepted by a Turing machine

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

Given a Turing machine, how can I identify the language it accepts and write a set notation for L(M)?

Comment: You identify the langauge in the same way that you identify what any computer program does: study it and figure it out. How to write something using set notation is an exceptionally broad question. Bear in mind that descriptions of languages aren't unique: there's more than one way to describe a set and any reasonably concise, unambiguous description will do.

Answer (score 3):

A Turing machine implements an algorithm.
The algorithm can be implicit by an explicit definition of the language such as:
$M$ is a TM such that $L(M)=\left \{ x\in \Sigma^* \ | \ |x|\in \mathbb{N}_{even}\right \}$. Which is usually the case.
In other cases, you might have to understand a turing machine based on a state diagram, this will be a simple reverse engineering problem where based on some inputs you understand the algorithm (and then you can prove your assumption).
Generally, there is no fixed approach towards understanding the language a machine accepts.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of identifying the language that is accepted by a Turing machine (using or not some form of set construction notation) does not have a general solution. This means that - with the exception of a minority of trivial cases - you will have to take them one at a time, as separate problems, *by logical necessity*.

The fact that this question constantly reappears (in different guises) just shows how its answer is counterintuitive. It may be worth noting that Turing proposed the model of computation that carries his name precisely to explore the limits of computation, so this negative result should not be treated as something unexpected, or surprising.